# Lookups in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, lookup

I have multiple lookups in pipeline mongo query. if any populate field is undefined I don't want to omit this row. can I do this?

```
const pipeline = [
  { $unwind: "$wholesaler" },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "serviceproviders",
      localField: "serviceProvider",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "serviceProvider"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$serviceProvider" },
  {
    $sort: {
      createdAt: 1,
      updatedAt: 1
    }
  }
];
```

If service provider id is not found its return rest of the object that what I want.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample document?

Answer (score 0):

From MongoDB [document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/):

> **preserveNullAndEmptyArrays**
>
> If true, if the path is
>   null, missing, or an empty array, $unwind outputs the document. If
>   false, $unwind does not output a document if the path is null,
>   missing, or an empty array.
>
> The default value is false.

So use below:

```
{
  $unwind: {
    path: "$serviceProvider",
    "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
  }
}
```

Check here with sample data (https://mongoplayground.net/p/aljWODXfwQg)